# scala: use implicits to support two different types for each argument to a method?

Tags: scala

suppose i have a method that takes a large number of arguments, each of which could be a String or a Seq[String]. inside the method, i want the value of each argument to be just the value if it was a String, and mkString " " on the Seq if it was a Seq[String]. i realize that Left/Right could possibly be used here but i don't want the caller to have to wrap any args.

i've used implicits to force the arg to be either a String or a Seq[String] but i can't figure out how to get the arg to reduce itself to a string, either as the identity or as mkString, depending on the case. the ideal code might look like this:

```
trait StrOrSeqStr[A]

implicit object Str extends StrOrSeqStr[String]
implicit object SeqStr extends StrOrSeqStr[Seq[String]]

def f[A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit a: StrOrSeqStr[A], implicit b: StrOrSeqStr[B]) {
  val aIn: String = a
  val bIn: String = b // converts strings to themselves, seq strings as _ mkString " "
}

// both should work
f(Seq("1"), "2")
f("1", Seq("2", "3"))
```

any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I understand you just need to convert `String` to `Seq[String]` implicitly. This simple implicit conversion should do it:

```
implicit def stringToSeqString(s: String) = Seq(s)

def f(a: Seq[String], b: Seq[String]) {
  val (aIn, bIn) = (a mkString " ", b mkString " ")
  // ...
}

f(Seq("1"), "2")
f("1", Seq("2", "3"))
```

Comment: ... or vice versa - a seq2String method.

Answer (score 3):

```
implicit def stringsToString(s: Seq[String]) = s mkString " "

def f(s: String *) {
   println(s mkString " ")
}

scala> f("1")
1

scala> f("1", "2")
1 2

scala> f(Seq("1", "2"))
1 2

scala> f(Seq("1"), Seq("2"))
1 2

scala> f("1", Seq("2"))
1 2

scala> f(Seq("1"), "2")
1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you tried to use context bounds in order to give function `f` something that can be treated as `String` or can be converted to it. I addition to my other answer I want to add other solution that uses type classes. It's more complicated, so I can advise you to use simple implicit conversion, that I described in another answer, if it solves your problem.

For demonstration purposes I renamed `StrOrSeqStr` to `Displayable` and made it more generic, so that it works not only for `String` and `Seq[String]`, but also for any other types and `Seq[T]` if type parameter `T` is also has `Displayable` for it (it actually can work with any class you want - you just need to provide suitable implicit).

At first you need to define `Displayable`:

```
trait Displayable[T] {
  def getString(target: T): String
}

object Displayable {
  implicit object StringDisplayable extends Displayable[String] {
    def getString(str: String) = str
  }

  implicit object DateDisplayable extends Displayable[Date] {
    val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy")
    def getString(date: Date) = dateFormat format date
  }

  implicit def seqDisplayable[T: Displayable] = new Displayable[Seq[T]] {
    def getString(seq: Seq[T]) = seq map implicitly[Displayable[T]].getString mkString " "
  }
}
```

As you can see I collected all related implicits in companion object, so that they would be always available and do not require explicit import (good for future usage).

Interesting method here is `seqDisplayable` - it requires `T` to also have `Displayable` (this also makes it recursive - so that `Seq[Seq[Date]]` for example would also have `Displayable`). I also created special rules for `String` and `Date`. So as you can see, it's pretty restrictive and allows `String`, `Date`, `Seq[String]`, `Seq[Date]`, `Seq[Seq[String]]`, `Seq[Seq[String]]`, etc. If you want to allow all other objects you can add something like this:

```
implicit def anythingDisplayable[T] = new Displayable[T] {
  def getString(anything: T) = anything toString
}
```

Now comes `f` function:

```
def f[A : Displayable, B : Displayable](a: A, b: B) {
  val aIn = implicitly[Displayable[A]].getString(a)
  val bIn = implicitly[Displayable[B]].getString(b)
  // ...
}
```

So I require evidence:  there should exist some `Displayable` for `A` and `B` and then I just convert them to `String` using these `Displayable`s. If you want to simplify it further, you can create implicit conversion from some type that has `Dislplayable` to `String`:

```
implicit def displayableToString[T : Displayable](target: T) =
      implicitly[Displayable[T]].getString(target)

def f[A : Displayable, B : Displayable](a: A, b: B) {
  val aIn: String = a
  val bIn: String = b
  //...
}
```

Here is example of usage:

```
f(Seq("1"), "2")
f("1", Seq("2", "3"))
f(new Date, Seq("10", "3"))
f(new Date, Seq(Seq("10", "11"), Seq("3", "4")))
f(Seq(new Date, new Date(12345)), "1")
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Close, very close...

```
trait StrOrSeqStr[A] {
  def mkString(x: A): String
}

implicit object Str extends StrOrSeqStr[String] { def mkString(s: String) = s }
implicit object SeqStr extends StrOrSeqStr[Seq[String]] {
    def mkString(s: Seq[String]) = s mkString " "
}

def f[A, B](a: A, b: B)(implicit evA: StrOrSeqStr[A], evB: StrOrSeqStr[B]) {
  implicit def fromSeqString(s: Seq[String]): String = s mkString ""
  val aIn: String = evA mkString a
  val bIn: String = evB mkString b
}

// both should work
f(Seq("1"), "2")
f("1", Seq("2", "3"))
```